# Lightswitch nested autocomplete boxes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, autocompletebox

I have Lightswitch 2013 and need to have nested autocomplete boxes.  All the examples on the Internet are for older versions of Lightswitch and there are just a few differences in their examples from my version.  Example: When adding Data Item for Local Property, Type "someTable" (Entity) doesn't come up as a choice.  Also, if I click on one of my tables, then when I drag this Local Property to the screen is doesn't create an autocomplete box.  Seems simple, but frustrating when I've tried many different ways.  Please provide specific example using Lightswitch 2013. Thanks in advance.  Steve

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

(1) Create a table called Customers(Id, Name) and a table called Orders(Id, CustomerId, Description)  Create a foreign key relationship between Customers.Id and Orders.CustomerId.

(2) Update your LightSwitch 2013 Data Source

(3) Create an Add/Edit screen using the Orders table.

(4) By Default, all the fields (Id, Customer, Description) should be included.  The Customer field should default to 'Details Picker'  (The Choices will be 'Auto' and will lookup Customers in the Customers table)

Note: The Details Picker will AutoComplete after you type a minimum of three characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  This appears to be the way to create an autocomplete box.  My initial question involves the subsequent steps:  Using the data from the first autocomplete box to filter the selections for the next (nested) autocomplete box.  Thanks.

Comment: Those are known to me as "cascading".  Same rules apply, with the addition of filters.  This can be done two ways. I prefer to use a LightSwitch query + PreprocessQuery.

Comment: Kris, please give me example (sample code).  Why the preprocessquery?

Comment: Have you used (or googled) PreprocessoryQuery? Basically you locate the table (Orders table) in the DataSource, right click and choose "Add Query", add a parameter (CustomerId long), click the Write Code drop down list and select the specific PreprocessQuery, and then write LINQ to filter the query results based on the input parameters, then you add the new Query to your screen, and after it's added you can change the Details Picker choices from "Auto" to the name of your query, then link up the parameter and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.  I figured it out myself.  I played around with displaying fields on my screens to see what was actually happening until I finally found out that I can add a specific data binding? to my properties and didn't have to use the drop down choices.  I've got it working now.
This seems like a basic requirement for using Lightswitch.  I wish someone would be able to post a detailed step by step solution to properly using nested autocomplete boxes.  I'm not sure I would remember how to do nexted autocomplete boxes if I had to do this again in a year.
When an expert, like a Beth Massi, provides a detailed example for a specific version of Visual Studio or Lightswitch, it would be nice if that expert, or his/her replacement, would provide a new detailed example whenever Visual Studio or Lightswitch has a new version.  Thanks for all the help I have received by searching the Internet.